# Deploying trufflesuite/ganache-cli docker image to Azure Container Instances with additional parameters

Tags: azure, docker, ganache

I want to deploy `trufflesuite/ganache-cli` docker image to Azure Container Instances and be able to pass parameters to ganache-cli, like `--accounts` or `--fork`.

When I try running `trufflesuite/ganache-cli:latest` image locally, everything works

> PS> `docker context use default`
> PS> `docker run --detach --publish 8545:8545 trufflesuite/ganache-cli:latest --accounts 10`
> e675e143ddc3ae2e6425700d18725f38360775c38fb0cb41e37a270e4fc5f83a

However, when I switch to Azure context, getting the error below

> PS> `docker context use ganacheacicontext`
> PS> `docker run --detach --publish 8545:8545 trufflesuite/ganache-cli:latest --accounts 10`
> [+] Running 0/1
> Group hopeful-mclean  Error
> 1.3s
> containerinstance.ContainerGroupsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request:
> StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="MoreImageRegistryCredentialsThanContainers" Message="**More image registry credentials provided than containers in container group** 'hopeful-mclean'."

I do have a resource group, context is correct, as when I try a different image, I am able to deploy it to ACI.

Now, when I use Azure cli I am able to deploy ganache-cli image to Azure Container Instances
`az container create --resource-group test-ganache --name ganache --image trufflesuite/ganache-cli:latest --ports 8545 --ip-address Public`

However, I can't figure out how to pass parameters to trufflesuite/ganache-cli when using az container create, like accounts, or fork, etc.
It fails with this error if I try to add `--accounts 10` to `az container create` line above:
`unrecognized arguments: --accounts 10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a ganache-cli parameter as one for the az container create command. Try using the **--command-line** parameter like this:

```
--command-line "ganache-cli -a 10"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was missing ganache-cli inside the args, wow, you saved me a lot of time!

Comment: It now throws the following error:
`container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"ganache-cli\": stat ganache-cli: no such file or directory": exit status 1: unknown`

This is the command I am using:
`az container create --resource-group testgroup --name ganache --image trufflesuite/ganache-cli:latest --ports 8545 --ip-address Public --command-line "ganache-cli -a 10"`

Any idea how to get the path of ganache-cli within the image?
https://hub.docker.com/r/trufflesuite/ganache-cli

Comment: Try running the image locally and open a session using docker exec, then locate the file's location.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, was able to view the contents and use this `--command-line "/app/ganache-core.docker.cli.js -a 10"`